# Custom Serializer with MongoDB, Jackson, and MongoJack

Tags: java, json, mongodb, serialization, jackson

I have a class that, when serialized, should serialize one of its members in its place. My class is:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyClassSerializer.class)
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    /**
     * A default ID for this class for serialization.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * A member of this object.
     */
    private final OtherClass otherClass;

    ...

    /**
     * Returns the instance of the member object.
     * 
     * @return The instance of the member object.
     */
    public OtherClass getOtherClass() {
        return otherClass;
    }
}
```

To accomplish this, I created a very simple custom serializer:

```
public class MyClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass> {
    /**
     * Serializes only the OtherClass field.
     */
    @Override
    public void serialize(
        final MyClass myClass,
        final JsonGenerator generator,
        final SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        // Write the schema.
        generator.writeObject(myClass.getOtherClass());
    }
}
```

This is the easiest (and, I believe, most correct) way to do something like this. Even if I wanted to, writing a custom serializer for OtherClass would be extremely complex because it is an abstract root class. This can be accomplished through Jackson, however, with a few annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = Id.NAME,
    include = As.PROPERTY,
    property = OtherClass.JSON_KEY_TYPE,
    defaultImpl = OtherClassDefault.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = SubOtherClass1.class,
        name = SubOtherClass1.TYPE_ID),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = SubOtherClass2.class,
        name = SubOtherClass2.TYPE_ID),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = SubOtherClass3.class,
        name = SubOtherClass3.TYPE_ID),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = SubOtherClass4.class,
        name = SubOtherClass4.TYPE_ID),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = SubOtherClass5.class,
        name = SubOtherClass5.TYPE_ID) })
@JsonAutoDetect(
    fieldVisibility = Visibility.DEFAULT,
    getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
    setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
    creatorVisibility = Visibility.DEFAULT)
public abstract class OtherClass implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

I have tested this using Jackson to serialize and deserialize instances of MyClass, and it works exactly as intended.

My application code is a little more complicated. I have a `ContainerClass` that has a member of type `MyClass`. I attempt to serialize an instance of `ContainerClass` through MongoJack:

```
// Get the authentication token collection.
JacksonDBCollection<ContainerClass, Object> collection =
    JacksonDBCollection
        .wrap(
            MongoBinController
                .getInstance()
                .getDb()
                .getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME),
            ContainerClass.class);

// Save it.
collection.insert(container);
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class my.package.MyClass
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:270)
    ...
```

I can get it to work if I remove the `@JsonSerialize` from `MyClass`, however this results in the entire `MyClass` instance being serialized, which is not what I want. This makes me almost sure that the problem lies in my custom serializer, but I am not sure how else I am supposed to write it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick note that may help: when using polymorphic types, method called will be:

```
serializeWithType(...)
```

and not `serialize(...)`. So you will need to implement that method; usually it will be something as simple as:

```
typeSer.writeTypePrefixForObject(value, jgen);
// implement actual content serialization, or delegate here:
this.serialize(...);
typeSer.writeTypeSuffixForObject(value, jgen);
```

but you may want to have a look at standard Jackson serializers. The only real distinction is that whereas `serialize` needs to output START_OBJECT, END_OBJECT directly, here we have to ask `TypeSerializer` to add those. This is necessary because `type id` inclusion may actually change these (I can elaborate on this, but for now that should be enough).

However: there may be much easier solution here. If you can add `@JsonValue` annotation on member you want to use instead of whole object (either directly, or via mix-in), that should do the trick:

```
@JsonValue
public OtherClass getOtherClass()...
```

and if you need to deserialize, you can use `@JsonCreator` like:

```
@JsonCreator
public MyClass(OtherClass surrogate) { ... }
```

Comment: Great! This answered my original question; I can't believe I never knew about `@JsonValue`. I tried the `@JsonCreator` but am having a little trouble. It is complaining that abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types (which **is** being done in the abstract class's annotations), have a custom deserializer (which is probably what I will just do), or be instantiated with additional type information (which I don't understand). Anyway, if you have a suggestion on how to fix this, that would be great, but, if not, the custom deserializer is already working. Thanks again!

Comment: Might be worth another question here or on mailing lists: I don't know off-hand, but it should be possible to resolve, whatever the problem is. But with custom deserializer, maybe not worth worrying about at this point.